# Soapui unexpected end of file

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm working on a project with Soapui when I send the request I have this error unexpected end of file here is my code:

```groovy
import java.io.FileNotFoundException
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.io.IOException
import java.util.Date
import java.io.*
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFDataFormat
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*
import com.opencsv.CSVReader
import com.opencsv.CSVWriter

CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\******\\Desktop\\Groovy Script test\\data.csv"))
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\******\\Desktop\\Groovy Script test\\Output.csv"))
//get property
propTestStep = context.testCase.getTestStepByName("PRO-Number-property") // get the Property step (ours is named "property-loop")
//loop
String [] nextLine 

while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null ) {
  writer.writeNext(nextLine)  
  log.info ("The value on the excel sheet is data " + nextLine[5])                 
  //assign value of pro
  propTestStep.setPropertyValue("PRO Number", (nextLine[2])) //set the value of Pro" property equal to Excel's column B ( getCell(1) )
  //Get node of the response
  testRunner.runTestStepByName("GetByProNumber") //we're going to run the Soap Request after each iteration of the Excel's rows.

  def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )

  if( "GetByProNumber#Response" == null){
    log.info("Null try again")
  } else {
    def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("GetByProNumber#Response")
    log.info (holder)
    holder.namespaces["ns"] = "http://www.SaiaSecure.com/WebService/Shipment"
    if (holder != null){
      writer.writeNext("${holder.getNodeValue('//ns:Activity')}", nextLine[0])  
      log.info("Node Response:${holder.getNodeValue('//ns:Activity')}")
    } else {
      log.info("Null try again")  
    }
  }

}// end of while loop    
//writer.close()
writer.close()
log.info ("Done" )
```

Please I want to know what I'm doing wrong Thanks for any help     I'm working on a project with Soapui when I send the request I have this error unexpected end of file here is my code:

Comment: Which line of code is causing this? You need to show the logs. May be you also need to look into the file that your are reading. The error you mentioned is very generic.

Comment: Thanks Rao for your reply I'm getting the error on this line def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("GetByProNumber#Response")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh ok, your comment is very useful to identify the issue.

That appears to be a trivial error.

**Change your code snippet from:**

```groovy
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("GetByProNumber#Response")
```

**To:**

```groovy
//Get the specified test step response and assign to variable
def stepResponse = context.expand('${GetByProNumber#Response}')
//Now pass the above variable to xmlholder to create the object
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(stepResponse)
```